# Не обычное подчеркивание у заголовков

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

Здравствуйте! При разработке одного сайта возникли трудности с реализацией некоторого подчеркивания у текста, много думал как это реализовать но еще так и не решил, в решении в приоритете Хром. В общем задача на картинке:[image: подчеркивание у заголовков]

Может кто-то реально с таким стыкался, или хотя бы идеи реализации, буду очень благодарен)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
h1{
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 700;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;  
  text-transform: uppercase;  
  letter-spacing: 15px;
}
h1:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: calc(100% - 12px); left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  background: #66C5C7;
}
h1 > span{
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<h1><span>title h1<span></h1>
```

Comment: Для многострочного текста не сработает.